# Data corruption when uploading a texture (Direct3D11)

Tags: intel, directx-11, direct3d

I have encountered the following issue in my Direct3D11-based application:
Sometimes (and on some machines) I get a texture which is seemingly corrupted, a couple of lines are just black. Something like this (showing one texture):
[image: corrupted texture]

Sometimes it is as bad as this, sometimes it is only one or two lines. I made sure that it is not a rendering issue; all observations indicate that the texture-data is not correct.

So far this has been observed only under the following conditions:

- we are creating an immutable texture (CPUAccessFlags=None, Usage=Default, BindFlags=ShaderResource)
- using a laptop with "Intel HD Graphics 520" and "AMD Radeon R7 M360" with Windows 7 (with ["AMD Enduro"-technology](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/enduro))
- only with texture-formats "R16G16B16A16_UNorm", "R8G8B8A8_UNorm", "R32_Float", not with "R8_UNorm" and "R16_UNorm" (for the rest it is unknown to me whether they work or not)
- and it seems to occur only intermittently (seems to be more likely if the GPU is quite busy)

I tried putting together a small sample which reproduces the issue: https://github.com/ptahmose/ImmutableTextureUploadTest

In this code, I am up-loading an immutable texture, then copy it to a staging texture, and then compare the data to what was up-loaded.
Now, with this repro-project I get the following:

- If this repro-application is running alone on the machine, all is fine.
- If I run another application which uses D3D11 on the machine, we get errors with this test-application.

I.e. this test-application reports errors if we run two instances of it (or, if I run the actual D3D11-based application).
[image]

Did somebody run across something similar? Can this issue be reproduced? Am I missing something? ...and of course: what are my options to solve/work around this issue?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try [WARP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082.aspx) to see if it repros.

Comment: No issues with WARP (or with other machines/GPUs - tested on quite a few machines with various Intel-, NVidia- or AMD-GPUs). I am suspecting that it is limited to "AMD Enduro" only, but I haven't had a chance to run it on an "Intel HD 520" without "AMD Enduro".